# Login failed for the user '' SQL Server when connecting using python from EMR server

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, odbc, pyodbc, unixodbc

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server Database from AWS EMR server.

```sh
$cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.8.so.1.1
UsageCount=1
```

and I modified the .odbc.ini file in my home directory like this.

```sh
$cat .odbc.ini
[ODBC Data Sources]
studylog = ODBC17Driver

[studylog]
Driver          = /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.8.so.1.1
Description     = My Description
Server          = hostname.amazonaws.com
```

output of `odbcinst -j` command

```
unixODBC 2.3.7
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /mnt/efs/home/username/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

output of `odbcinst -q -d` command

`[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]`

output of `odbcinst -q -s` command

`[studylog]`

Python script I'm using to connect to SQL Server

```py
import pyodbc

host = "hostname.amazonaws.com"
user="DBUser"
password="Password"
db="dbname"

details = {
 'server' : host,
 'database' : db,
 'username' : user,
 'password' : password
 }

# ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
connect_string = 'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};SERVER={server};PORT={{1433}}; DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}'.format(**details)
connection = pyodbc.connect(connect_string)
print(connection)
```

output of my python script

```
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'DBUser'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

What's going wrong in this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Aside... I'm surprised you're not getting an "invalid connection string" error before it even attempts to connect since `PORT` is not a supported [Connection String Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/dsn-connection-string-attribute). If you need to specify a port then the normal way to supply a port number is with `SERVER=tcp:ServerNameOrIpAddress,PortNumber;`

Comment: Do you have remote access to the SQL Server instance? Check the ERRORLOG for error 18456 lines then check the State number on those lines against [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to see what the cause of the error condition is.

Comment: At a guess there's a mismatch between `studylog_db="dbname"`, `'database' : db` and `DATABASE={database};`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the mismatch is a mistake in question creation. I corrected it

Comment: modified the connection string like this `host = "tcp:hostname.amazonaws.com,1433";
connect_string = 'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}'.format(**details)` and it's working. Thank you so much